# Listen for a state change of AngularUI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to know if a user is going to a specific state, and I plan on using ng-animate to make it slide in.

Is there a way listen to an event that will pass the state that user clicked/changed and then append a class to the `<ui-view>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can listen to the [State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events), **$stateChangeStart** in your case.

Create the handler function for this event and inside add the CSS class to your element.